# Convert the html into image , and save it ?(use html2canvas.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html2canvas

I have a big problem,
please help me !
This is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#show_button").click(function() {
        html2canvas(document.body, {
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
            $("<img/>", {
              id: "image",
              src: canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
              width: '95%',
              height: '95%'
            }).appendTo($("#show_img").empty());
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <button id="show_button">Show Image</button>

  //this is a problem
  <a href="" download="dl.jpg">download</a>
  <div id="show_img"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

If my viewpoint is correct .
To save image,the download need the correct file path and file name.
And i use the html2canvas.js , convert the target into image .
But when i want to save the image , i don't know the correct file path and file name.(Because the image is dynamic file ,not a static file?)
How can i get the correct value to save this image?
Thank you!

Comment: See example http://www.freakyjolly.com/convert-html-document-into-image-jpg-png-from-canvas/

Answer (score 4):

OK, I've discovered canvas2image.js that does what you need with this function

```
downloadPNG = function () {
  html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
      Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
    }
  });
}
```

Here is a **fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/w8Lk3znf/

Comment: Hi,thank your answer!
It's very helpful in this question.
But now i have a new small question.
If use this website provide compiler,it will run success.
But the download file doesn't have the filename extension,like ".png".
Just have the name "download".
(But i rename this file to "download.png,it can open.")

Comment: Then i run in local,it does't download anything.

So i add "  download='dl.png'  " this code in <a> ,like <a href="" onclick="downloadPNG()" download="dl.png">download</a>.
It will download,but it will download 2 file,one is "download" ,the other is "dl.png".
And the "dl.png" is incorrect file that can't open it.

How can i download the file ,and the file is correct(and i can use other name for rename the file name.)?

We can solve this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use html2canvas it will convert html to canvas and use canvas2image packages to convert canvas to image (or) you can pass canvas data .toDataURL("image/png");

example:

```
var imagename = '<YOUR_IMAGE_NAME>';
var link = event.target;
var canvasData = '<YOUR_CANVAS_DATA>'.toDataURL("image/png");
downloadImageFormat(link, canvasData, imagename);
function downloadImageFormat(link, canvasData, imagename) {
    link.href = canvasData;
    link.download = imagename;
}
```

Here is fiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Just Use **html2canvas** **library** just include plugin and call method to convert HTML to Canvas then download as image PNG

```
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("image-wrap")).then(function(canvas) {
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.download = "manpower_efficiency.jpg";
            link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
            link.target = '_blank';
            link.click();
        });
```

**Source**: http://www.freakyjolly.com/convert-html-document-into-image-jpg-png-from-canvas/